# Making a ul li drop on click using only css and not javascript

Tags: html, css

Hi friends i want to make a side menu ,now i have one (built using html lists  ).But the problem is i don't know how to make the subcategories(sub lists) 
i have put my codes here .I want the sub category drop down while clicking it

```html
<ul class="droplist">
  <li>Category
  </li>

  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> FOOD ITEMS
    </li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> TOYS
    </li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> GIFTS
    </li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Fruits
    </li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>GADGETS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>TOYS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>BAGGAGES</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>FLOWERS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>ELECTRONICS</li>
  </a>
  <a>
    <li><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>SPORTS</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: "clicks" require javascript not CSS

Comment: can it be done using hover?

Comment: Yes, it can...I'd sugegst you do some more research. There re hundreds of tutorials online about CSS menus on hover.

Comment: You can do the "checkbox trick" or use the `:target` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for multiple droplists, try this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="dropdown-3" class="dropdown dropdown-processed">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Options</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $('div.dropdown').each(function() {
          var $dropdown = $(this);

          $("a.dropdown-link", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $div = $("div.dropdown-container", $dropdown);
            $div.toggle();
            $("div.dropdown-container").not($div).hide();
            return false;
          });

        });

        $('html').click(function(){
          $("div.dropdown-container").hide();
        });

      });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You stack them like this:

```
  <ul>
      <li>myItem 1</li>
      <li>myItem 2</li>
      <li>
         <ul>
           <li>myItem 2a</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>myItem 3</li>
     <li>myItem 4</li>
</ul>
```

Or maybe you want to do it differently, by combining the `<details>` and
`<summary>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
          .droplist li ul{
            display: none;
          }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="droplist">
      <li><a href="#">Category</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> FOOD ITEMS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> TOYS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> GIFTS </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Fruits</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".droplist li").click(function(){
              $(".droplist li ul").toggle();
          });
      });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes ,this one works .but is there any way to make multiple droplists .I mean when i try to open one ,the other lists also gets opened